# getResourceAsStream - What encoding is it read as?

Tags: java, file-io

I am using [getResourceAsStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) to access a local file. What encoding does it assume the file is?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`InputStream`s don't have encodings. They're just streams of bytes. [Reader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html)s are for text with an encoding. You can create a `Reader` with a specific charset from an `InputStream` like this:

```
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");
```

If you're using a charset that's guaranteed to be supported on all Java platforms like UTF-8, you can avoid having to deal with impossible `UnsupportedEncodingException`s by using a constant from [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com)'s `Charsets` class like `Charsets.UTF_8`.

Comment: Why do you need Guava for that?

Comment: @Casebash: I just mentioned Guava because it makes working with charsets a bit more convenient. You don't need Guava to use readers or charsets (though it does have some awesome utilities for making things easier beyond what I mentioned here).

Comment: Since Java 1.7, you can use `StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()` to get the "UTF-8" constant.

Comment: @LaurentG: But there shouldn't generally be any need to actually get the name... most APIs (such as `InputStreamReader`) that could take a `String` for the charset name should also have a version that takes a `Charset` directly.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how to use encoding in `getResourceStream()`, generally you can query the `file.encoding` property or `Charset.defaultCharset()` to find the current default encoding.it is better to explicitly specify the desired encoding (i.e. "UTF-8") in the code. In this way, it will work even across different platforms.

Also how to read a file , you can look at this post  [How to create a Java String from the contents of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326390/how-to-create-a-java-string-from-the-contents-of-a-file)  Jon Skeet's answer.